# Can google maps or Apple Maps be used in IOS development as a game board

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps

I am trying to develop an app as a project and thought of a game that would use an actual map of a city or town as its game board where then "pegs", "icons" or "players" would be moved to different locations.  In my head I have ideas for most every aspect, except for how to make this work.  So the direct question is, does anyone know of a way to use swift to use Apple maps or Google Maps as a game board where i can set specific locations for game pieces to move around to?

Comment: Once you figure out how to get the map onto the screen, which there are lots of guides for, it is simply a matter of reading the documentation of the API and seeing what you can do to it. Then see how you can manipulate it to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something simple like the [smarty pins](https://smartypins.withgoogle.com/) game. You can do the same in an iOS app. For this you need to consider three things:

- Google Maps SDK for iOS
- Places API
- Direction API

Store the question in SQLite DB for this app and fetch it whenever a new question is requested.

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift) will give you most of the idea of how to implement that. Rest of the creativity you have to put on your own!!

Comment: so AniV, reading the tutorials, it seems to allow for global areas.  Is there a way to constrain it to a specific city area?

Comment: You can always use the radius parameter in you Google Places API to define the region covered you want to make a search to.
Refer to the following official documentation for more details https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests